# Edit Form Submit handler for a Model

Tags: python, django, forms, wagtail

I have a fairly simple django model in a Wagtail CMS; essentially:

```django
from django.db import models

class Thingy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    # Many other fields.

    panels = [
        FieldPanel("name"),
        # ...
    ]
```

I need to perform an action when this model is saved **via the Wagtail model edit form** (eg `/admin/section/thingy/123/edit`).

Currently, I have registered a post_save signal, however this has resulted in the method being called when the model is saved programmatically (via an import sync task).

I've had a look in the Django docs, but can't see anything obvious... is there a way to register a signal for the form submission (ideally after the internal submission and save is handled).

(If it's any relevance; I need to trigger a search reindex based on a relation to the model; anything that references instance 123 of thing Things that was saved needs to be reindexed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ModelAdmin, you can [customize your edit view](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/reference/contrib/modeladmin/primer.html#overriding-views) and put your reindexing code in there.

Comment: Thank you @cnk - I know it'd be something I missed!